# How to to insert data to a bridge table simultaneously with other connecting tables

Tags: c++, mysql

Hi all how I have a product, order and product order(bridge entity) table.
Im building a cart based order system c++ program where when user make a new order ,it will have product id listed on a list and every product will have its own orderID. Im kinda confused on the sql side on how to insert data that have brige entity and join them together

*The table have the following attrbs*

Table product

```
ProductID
```

Table Order1

```
OrderID,
Totalprice,
description,
agentid
```

Table product_order(bridge entity)

```
ProductID, 
OrderID, 
quantity
```

I'm planning to insert data only 1 time simultaneously inserting into the other table as well . Its possible to use join + insert?

Comment: Just do two `INSERT`s in one transaction.

Comment: You can only insert into one table at a time.

Comment: can you show the example to do two insert in one transaction? @stickybit